# Android - Activity Not Found Exception

Tags: android

I am using startActivity to call another Activity and I get the "Activity Not Found Exception".  Here is my code:

```
  TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;
  String strText = textView.getText().toString();
  String key = "symptom";
  Intent mIntent = new Intent(symptomActivity.this, symptomRemedyActivity.class);
  Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
  mBundle.putString(key, strText);
  mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
  startActivity(mIntent);
```

Here is the Logcat output:

```
INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.android.homeopathy/.HomeopathyActivity: 5542 ms (total 39089 ms)
INFO/ARMAssembler(59): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [ 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x3283e0:0x3284ec] in 627000 ns
INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.homeopathy/.symptomActivity }
INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.android.homeopathy/.symptomActivity: 2706 ms (total 2706 ms)
INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.homeopathy/.symptomRemedyActivity (has extras) }
```

Here is the debug window output:

```
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ActivityNotFoundException)) 
Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(int, Object) line: 1404    
Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Context, IBinder, IBinder, Activity, Intent, int) line: 1378  
symptomActivity(Activity).startActivityForResult(Intent, int) line: 2817    
symptomActivity(Activity).startActivity(Intent) line: 2923  
symptomActivity$1.onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int, long) line: 67    
ListView(AdapterView).performItemClick(View, int, long) line: 284   
ListView.performItemClick(View, int, long) line: 3382   
AbsListView$PerformClick.run() line: 1696   
ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

symptomRemedyActivity is another activity in my project.  Is there something I need to do like importing symptomRemedyActivity so that startActivity can see symptomRemedyActivity, to remove this "Activity Not Found Exception"?

Comment: If you were using eclipse and/or looking at the logcat it would ask you if you declared it in the manifest

Comment: I am using eclipse with logcat.  Logcat says nothing about the manifest.  I have listed the logcat output in my question along with the Debug window output.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but it's on top of the google search at the moment, so for anyone who would come here later: `ActivityNotFound` can be caused by unhandled exceptions in your `onCreate` in the activity you're trying to create. It took me a while to notice that I was causing a `nullPointerException` there, because I wasn't looking for it.

Comment: And this is exactly what was making chaos for me too :-)

Comment: I would upvote this answer a dozen times if I could.  I wasted so much time double, triple, and quadruple checking that I had correctly declared my activity in the application manifest when the real problem was what you described here.

Answer (score 33):

Did you list the activity (symtomRemedyActivity) within your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: I added activity (symtomRemedyActivity) within my AndroidManifest.xml file, did a Refresh and I still get the error.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I was just having.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have added the following to the Manifest File

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 6):

Stuck with the same error for an hour only to realize that I have to clean and build again. Apparently, some times changes in xml do not reflect until we clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly forgot to declare the activity in the manifest file AndroidManifest.xml as follows (you need to inject the value you actually got):

```
   <activity
        android:name="symptomRemedyActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ symptomRemedy"
        android:parentActivityName="MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.salvopaverani.databes"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.1" >
```

At manifest file, i try to change the android:versionName from 1.0 to 1.1 and everything OK.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding activity to **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your two activities (symptomActivity and symptomRemedyActivity) are in different packages, you have to declare in Android Manifest the package name.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to start SERVICE with `startActivity(intent)` and the same exception popped out. To run SERVICE, use `startService(intent)`

Answer (score 0):

Not only need you add your Activity in AndroidMainifest.xml like this:

```
<activity 
        android:name=".MyActivity"
       ></activity>
```

but also you should confirm your package path.

For example,my activity is in com.demo package. The head of the AndroidMainifest should write the same package path,like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.demo"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer which Unfrog has given.

One way to get the `NullPointerException` is to execute a code which is referring to the view parts before the `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Application tags in Manifest can cause this.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.Deleted bin and lib folder from project directory, recreated libs folder and pasted libs .everything started working. It was v4 lib that was culprit.