# Forced shutdown android

Tags: android, android-intent

For some reason, my newly made class will not receive the intent from the previous class, and causes the app to shutdown (this only happens with this class, not with other classes)

Here's my code:

```
 package com.WNF;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.content.Intent;


 public class Actiemenu extends ListActivity{

 @Override 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView (R.layout.actiemenu);

final String[] array = new String[] {
        "Ding", "AnderDing", "Nogeending", "laatseding"
    };

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.actiemenu, array));
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);



lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        if (position == 0) {
            Intent een = new Intent(v.getContext(), Acties.class);
            startActivity(een);
        }
        else if (position == 1) {
            Intent twee = new Intent(v.getContext(), Acties2.class);
            startActivity(twee);
        }
    }
    });
getIntent();
    }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong??

EDIT: Logcat stack:

[image: logcat stack]
<sub>(source: [alphalife-roleplay.com](http://www.alphalife-roleplay.com/logcat.png))</sub>

Comment: Please attach an exception stack from Logcat.

Comment: Really, another screenshot? Don't people know how to copy the output and paste it as text? The screenshot doesn't show it but it says `have you declared this activity in the manifest` there

Comment: @Lars..can you show your manifest file code please! because i guess you missing Activity entry in manifest file as per 5th line of your Exception log-cat.

Comment: can you post the code you are using to launch this activity?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens to me when I for get to add the activity to the **AndroidManifest.xml**

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: nope, i did forget it, but it still doenst work when i added it :(

Comment: If you could post the stack we probably could help better.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533370/android-activity-not-found-exception) question you're most likely to have an unhandled exception in your `onCreate()` method.

Is it a full call stack? You might have a string like "...caused by..." which will point you to the place in the code where exception occurs (if any).

Answer (score 0):

The way I do my list views is to change the name of the activity by setting it to:

"com.whateveryouhavehere." + yourarray[v]

Place this in the onItemClicked

That should have it go to the correct activity.

Right now you are telling it to go to the name based on which part of the array is clicked.

You need to use the name you set for the activity in the manifest, not the class name.