# Android Intent.setClass not able to get to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android development and I am currently working on my first android app. The task is to scan an QR code and extract the information from the result, further get the webpage link and access the information on that webpage. I currently created two activities, one is QR code scanner(MainActivity1), and the other is to get the information of the webpage (MainActivity).

I would like to call MainActivity in MainActivity1 using intent.setClass, however, when I run the program it always occurs error and shut down. Probably I put this in a wrong place, so it could not start the other activity. I checked the log file and apparently the problem occurs in startActivity(intent).

The following is the handleResult part of QR code scanner code in MainActivity1

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
   ........
   ........

    public void displayAlertMessage(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity1.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", listener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
    @Override
    public void handleResult(final Result result) {
        final String scanResult = result.getText();
        ArrayList<String> res = getWebLink(result);
        Log.d("msg", "pass1");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity1.this);
            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MainActivity1.this, MainActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArrayList("urls", res);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        builder.setMessage(scanResult);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getWebLink(final Result result){
        final String scanResult = result.getText();
        String[] res = scanResult.split("\\;");

        final ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
            if(res[i].length() != 10){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                if(Character.isLetter(res[i].charAt(0)) && Character.isLetter(res[i].charAt(1))){
                    words.add("https://drugs.olc.tw/drugs/index/"+res[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return words;
    }

}
```

Could someone tell me where I get it wrong? Thank you!

Edit:
[image: Console]

Edit:(Manifest file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tsen0406.qrcodeapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: if an error occurs then there is a corresponding entry in Logcat - please share this as well

Comment: Can you post your manifest file too

Comment: @0X0nosugar I post the console msg, not sure if it helps. If u need Logcat I will try to share later

Comment: @varunkr I post the manifest file now

Comment: It's ok but next time better post text not screenshots (easier to search for users in the same situation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Activity Not Found Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533370/android-activity-not-found-exception)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `MainActivity` to the manifest too, just like your added you `MainActivity1`

Add this to your manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```